# Online tool for warm up a webpage?

Tags: caching

I have a web page that do some stuff and return (and cache) an output. 
I want to warm up the cache daily, is there an online tool where I can schedule this?

Answer (score 0):

I found a free method: use IFTTT with time trigger and Webhooks for call the page